# What do I get as output when compiling wxWidgets as per instructions?

Tags: mingw, wxwidgets

I downloaded wxWidgets sources and followed the instructions found here:
https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2.3/plat_msw_install.html
I installed MinGW from this file:
winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-12.2.0-mingw-w64ucrt-10.0.0-r4.zip
it compiles fine and also as instructed the minimal sample compiles.
Now I wonder if I have libs for a 32 or 64 bit application. Also I downloaded from github all available packages wxMSW-3.2.3_gcc1220_xxx.7z, but to none of them the files I created are identical.
What are the differences?
And finally the minimal sample compiles to an exe of 97MB ! I found webpages talking about 4MB. How comes this huge difference. Which minimal size can be achhieved with the latest version of wxWidgets? I don't care about 1 or 2 MB but almost 100MB for an empty window seems to be very much.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You get the output corresponding to the compiler you use. From the name of the file, which contains `i686`, you must be using a 32-bit compiler.

As for the size, most of these 100MB are debugging symbols. You can strip your binary using `strip` command to significantly reduce its size (but you won't be able to debug it comfortably). Normal size of statically linked minimal sample in the release build should indeed be a few MBs (it would be much smaller when using shared libraries, but that's not a fair comparison).

Comment: So a 32-bit compiler can only compile for 32-bit applications while a 64-bit compiler can compile for both- right? If so, which compiler flag do I need to tell a 64-bit compiler to compile for a 32-bit application.

Comment: And second question: why do I get a different lib than the 32-bit I downloaded? Are there different types of MinGW GCC12.2? (MSYS, Cygwin ...). Sorry I am not an expert on this. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Martin_from_K, the library difference, as already explained by Vadim, comes from the Debug vs Release builds.

Comment: @Martin_from_K, as for the flags - I believe you should be using `-m32` to compile for 32 bit application.

Comment: The library may be different due to the use of different build options or maybe slightly different compiler version. In general I'm not sure if wxMSW fields are fully reproducible (wxGTK ones are or at least can be).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Here are my results:
I ran strip minimal.exe on the 97 MB exe and got an exe with 6.3MB size
I built wxWidgets libs with BUILD=release and then built minimal.exe, resulting in 9.8MB size. After running strip on this I got 6.9 MB size.

Comment: It's strange that the release version is bigger than the debug one, but at least these numbers are in the right ballpark now.